# Phone verification Textfield Design in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm making an app in that i want to make an UI for phone verification textfields.It has four codes to be input which you will get via notification from our backend.
can you guys suggest something, i'm new to flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PinCodeTextField https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

You can use different shapes and animations also it handles the problem which occurs when you remove the text in middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome package for code  [pin_code_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_text_field)

It's a beautiful and highly customizable Flutter `widget` for entering pin code. Suitable for use cases such as `login` and `OTP`.